# Does "clandestine ignorance" make sense?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, expressions

Does the following make sense, "clandestine ignorance"? I would like to see if anyone else is thinking the same way as to the meaning or definition as I do. Thanks.

Comment: What meaning or definition do you apply to it? I got nothin'

Comment: I could guess what one **might** read into that phrase, but it's certainly opaque.

Comment: all the clandestine things happening in the world and the ignorance of the masses to all of it.

Comment: But as the first term refers to the last, what you get is the implication that some subject's ignorance is clandestine...

Comment: "hidden ignorance" makes sense. "Clandestine" has the connotation of 'purposeful' or 'sneaky' which implies some measure of intelligence. "ignorance', though literally means 'absence of knowledge', connotes lack of cleverness. So an ignorance that is clandestine is somewhat incongruous or unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard this phrase before, but what came to mind is Mr. Bean especially in the movie "Bean".

> Mr. Bean (Rowan Atkinson) is a security guard at the Royal National
>   Gallery in London, though his reputation for sleeping on the job
>   compels the board of directors to attempt to fire him, though they are
>   thwarted by the chairman (Sir John Mills) who is sympathetic with him.
>   In order to rid themselves of Bean, the board send him to Los Angeles
>   to represent them at the unveiling of the portrait Whistler's Mother,
>   which has been purchased for $50 million by the fictional Grierson Art
>   Gallery with a grant from General Newton (Burt Reynolds), and the
>   visit is arranged by the gallery's curator, David Langley (Peter
>   MacNicol), who is impressed with the National Gallery's false profile
>   of "Dr. Bean" and agrees to accommodate Bean in his house for two
>   months, much to the chagrin of his wife Allison (Pamela Reed), son
>   Kevin (Andrew Lawrence) and daughter Jennifer (Tricia Vessey), who
>   subsequently leave for Allison's mother's house.

The gallery's curator thinks "Dr. Bean" is a genius even tough he is a moron because of "clandestine ignorance".

Answer (score 0):

**Clandestine ignorance**: As clandestine is an adjective, this phrase suggests that **ignorance** is **secret** which doesn't make any sense.

Now you say in the comments:

> all the clandestine things happening in the world and the ignorance of the masses to all of it

We ignore those things which we know exist. For example: "He ignored the fat boy." Note that if he did not know that there was a fat boy, then he would not have been able to ignore him.

Clandestine suggests that something is secret, and something which is secret is not known, then how would you ignore it?

Comment: But "ignorance" doesn't mean "ignoring", it means "absence of knowledge". You're right about "clandestine ignorance", but there's nothing contradictory about the concept the OP is looking for. If anything it's somewhat tautologous though. If the masses knew about these things then they'd hardly be "clandestine".